# 500 internal error after create admin information in mautic 5.0.2 installation

Tags: installation, internal-server-error, mautic

I tried this command to install Mautic in xampp/htdocs folder.

**composer create-project mautic/recommended-project:^5 mautic --no-interaction**
and
**composer install**

Then I couldn't access server, so I've clear that codes like this.Check the .htaccess in docroot folder.
[to access server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyYDB.png)

I tried install mautic in my local host.
So set database and admin information according every installation steps.
After installation[database setup in local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWvz2.png)
[admin setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyxHI.png)
Then I press the next and that error occurred.
**"Uh oh! I think I broke it. If I do it again, please report me to the system administrator!
500 Internal Server Error"**
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOIGl.png)
How can i fix it?

Comment: can you check apache server log /etc/logs/apache2/error_log  if you are using httpd then /etc/logs/httpd/error_log